# ReactJs: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' when using map() method in ReactJs that return JSX(MaterialUi-icons) inside the array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, jsx, vite

i have a file constant.js which contains object name and icon as key. so the key icon contains the **icon component from @mui/icons-material** and when I try to get the value from the icon but instead I get an error.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'.

## constants.js

```
import  { Home }  from "@mui/icons-material";
import { Code } from "@mui/icons-material";
import { OndemandVideo } from "@mui/icons-material";
import { SportsEsports } from "@mui/icons-material";
import { LiveTv } from "@mui/icons-material";

export const categories = [
   {name: 'New', icon: <Home/> },
   {name: 'Coding', icon: <Code/>},
   {name: 'ReactJS', icon: <Code/>},
   {name: 'NextJS', icon: <Code/>},
   {name: 'Music', icon: <MusicNote/>},
   {name: 'Education', icon: <School/>},
   {name: 'Podcast', icon: <GraphicEq/>},
   {name: 'Movie', icon: <OndemandVideo/>},
   {name: 'Gaming', icon: <SportsEsports/>},
   {name: 'Live', icon: <LiveTv/>},
```

when i trying to **map()** the categories, it should be able return the value of icon that contains the icon components but it doesn't works...

## Sidebar.jsx

```
import { Stack } from "@mui/material"

import { categories } from "../utils/constans"

const Sidebar = () => {
  return (
      <Stack>
         {categories.map((category) => (
            <button key={category.name} className="category-btn"> 
               <span>{category.icon}</span> 
               <span>{category.name}</span>
            </button>
         ))}
      </Stack>
   )
}

export default Sidebar
```

but when i remove the '<' in the icons but this heppened.

> Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {$$typeof, type, compare}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: Your constants.js needs the jsx extension

Comment: yoww!! it's workss, i wanna cry looking for where the mistake in 3 hours. Thank you so much for ur help...

Answer (score 3):

JSX notation such as `<Home/>` are not pure Javascript and therefore they aren't valid in a `.js` file.

Change the file extension to `.jsx` wherever you use the `<Home/>` notation.